# form redirection

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm building a test web application ASP.NET VB from a tutorial see it at http://www.latinosnetwork.net/aspnetsystem/Login.aspx after successful log-in using user name jose and password abad the formsauthentication.redirectfromloginpage method redirect the application to a default.aspx at the root directory where it do not exist also the application is not at the root directory.

Any help on that.

**Edit**

still not work here is the configuration:

```
<location path="wwwroot/aspnetsystem"> 
    <system.web> 
        <customErrors mode="Off"/> 
        <authentication mode="Forms"> 
            <forms defaultUrl="wwwroot/aspnetsystem/Default.aspx" /> 
        </authentication> 
        <authorization> 
            <allow users="*" /> 
        </authorization> 
    </system.web> 
</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the default page you want redirected to in web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms defaultUrl="index.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: still not work here is the configuration:
 <location path="wwwroot/aspnetsystem">
        <system.web>
            <customErrors mode="Off"/>
            <authentication mode="Forms">
                <forms defaultUrl="wwwroot/aspnetsystem/Default.aspx" />
            </authentication>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>

Comment: @user295454: I added your comment to the question.

Comment: please provide an structure of your web application.